# Jquery-ui and animate bugs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

currently I'm facing some problems with jquery-ui and animate functions when running multiple of them together, I'm not sure whether I used it wrongly or what, but I just can't get the stop() working correctly.

For example when mouseover on a div, it will animate something, then mouseout it will animate something else, but when mouseover and out rapidly then it will have problem.. can anyone help me out on this?

and here is the full html+js:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>jtest</title>
<link rel="Shortcut Icon" href="favicon.ico" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
function showbox2() {
    $('#box2').show().animate({
        opacity: 1,
        top: '+=1025'
      }, 1200, 'easeOutExpo');
}
function runbox2() {
    $(".box2_img").show("fade", 800);
    $('.box2').cycle({
        fx: 'fade', // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
        timeout: 3500
    });
}
function xbox2() {
    $(".box2x").stop().show("blind", { direction: "horizontal" }, 500);
    $(".box3").stop().hide("blind", { direction: "horizontal" }, 800);
}
function hbox2() {
    $(".box2x").stop().hide("blind", { direction: "horizontal" }, 500);
    $(".box3").stop().show("blind", { direction: "horizontal" }, 800);
}
function showbox3() {
    $('#box3').show().animate({
        opacity: 1,
        right: '-=1000'
      }, 1200, 'easeOutExpo');
}
function runbox3() {
    $(".box3_img").show("fade", 800);
    $('.box3').cycle({
        fx: 'scrollRight', // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
        timeout: 4500
    });
}
function xbox3() {
    $(".box3x").stop().show("blind", { direction: "horizontal" }, 500);
    $(".box2").stop().hide("fade", 800);
}
function hbox3() {
    $(".box3x").stop().hide("blind", { direction: "horizontal" }, 500);
    $(".box2").stop().show("fade", 800);
}
function showbox9() {
    $('#box9').show().animate({
        opacity: 1,
        right: '+=1241'
      }, 1200, 'easeOutExpo');
}
function runbox9() {
    $(".box9_img").show("fade", 800);
    $('.box9').cycle({
        fx: 'scrollRight', // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
        timeout: 4800
    });
}
function showbox10() {
    $('#box10').show().animate({
        opacity: 1,
        right: '-=1000'
      }, 1200, 'easeOutExpo');
}
function runbox10() {
    $(".box10_img").show("fade", 800);
    $('.box10').cycle({
        fx: 'turnUp', // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
        timeout: 3800
    });
}
function showbox11() {
    $('#box11').show().animate({
        opacity: 1,
        bottom: '-=1000'
      }, 1200, 'easeOutExpo');
}
function runbox11() {
    $(".box11_img").show("fade", 800);
    $('.box11').cycle({
        fx: 'zoom', // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
        timeout: 7700
    });
}
function xbox11() {
    $(".box11x").stop().show("blind", { direction: "vertical" }, 500);
    $(".box9").stop().hide("explode", { direction: "vertical" }, 1000);
    $(".box10").stop().hide("explode", { direction: "vertical" }, 1000);
}
function hbox11() {
    $(".box11x").stop().hide("explode", { direction: "vertical" }, 1000);
    $(".box9").stop().show("blind", { direction: "vertical" }, 500);
    $(".box10").stop().show("blind", { direction: "vertical" }, 500);
}
function showit() {
    document.getElementById('loading_msg').style.display=('none');
    setTimeout("showbox2()",500);
    setTimeout("showbox3()",800);
    setTimeout("showbox9()",1300);
    setTimeout("showbox10()",1500);
    setTimeout("showbox11()",1800);

    setTimeout("runbox2()",1200);
    setTimeout("runbox3()",1800);
    setTimeout("runbox9()",2500);
    setTimeout("runbox10()",2800);
    setTimeout("runbox11()",2800);

}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
</head>

<body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" onload="showit();">
<div id="outer-container">
    <div id="loading_msg">Loading, please wait ...</div>

    <div id="container">
        <div id="box2" class="box2" onmouseover="xbox2();">
            <div class="box2_img" style="background-color:#F00; width:199px; height:233px;"></div>
            <div class="box2_img" style="background-color:#0F0; width:199px; height:233px;"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="box2x" class="box2x" onmouseout="hbox2();">
            <div class="box2_imgx" style="display:block; background-color:#FFF;"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="box3" class="box3" onmouseover="xbox3();">
            <div class="box3_img" style="background-color:#F00; width:196px; height:233px;"></div>
            <div class="box3_img" style="background-color:#0F0; width:196px; height:233px;"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="box3x" class="box3x" onmouseout="hbox3();">
            <div class="box3_imgx" style="display:block; background-color:#FFF;"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="box9" class="box9">
            <div class="box9_img" style="background-color:#F00; width:199px; height:118px;"></div>
            <div class="box9_img" style="background-color:#0F0; width:199px; height:118px;"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="box10" class="box10">
            <div class="box10_img" style="background-color:#F00; width:196px; height:118px;"></div>
            <div class="box10_img" style="background-color:#0F0; width:196px; height:118px;"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="box11" class="box11" onmouseover="xbox11();">
            <div class="box11_img" style="background-color:#fff; width:405px; height:203px;"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="box11x" class="box11x" onmouseout="hbox11();">
            <div class="box11_imgx" style="display:block; background-color:#FFF;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!
=)

Comment: .mouseenter() .mouseleave() http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/

Comment: Thanks, a useful functions that new to me, however I still can't get it work, (still trying out now):
<script>
 $(".box11").mouseenter(function(){
  xbox11();
 }).mouseleave(function(){
  hbox11();
 });
</script>

Comment: Ok, its work now, but the problem still there, which is when mouseenter/leave too fast, then the page crash~~

Answer (score 0):

can you make a simpler example or describe exactly what should happen and what is happening please and I'll fix. I have seen it where, when spamming events, certain variables are not reset properly but until I cn see the shortened code its kind of difficult working out what you actually want to happen.

Thanks

Comment: @JatinDhoot he can't comment post due to low reputation, you made it even lower

Comment: OK eicto --------- Was not knowing that ------------ I tried to upvote but my vote is locked for the time being. But "fool" is still not digestible :)

Comment: okay no more flaming. Ill apologize now I didn't realise about the comment vs answer thing. Lets see if he makes a simpler example. @JatinDhoot apologies for fool comment

Comment: Hi, chill guys, I've ady spam the full html+js here, have a look and let me know if there any clues, u may go to the site if u wanna c demo, thanks! =)